# Backup/restore data multiple sets of data for selected Android apps

Tags: gratis, android, backup, data

I'm seeking recommendations for an Android app that will backup/restore **data** for selected apps ***and*** maintain multiple versions of the data.

The paid version of Titanium Backup does this, but I'm looking for a gratis solution.

Note that root apps are fine, just please specify whether or not the app requires root for this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

**[Helium - App Sync and Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup)** (originally named *Carbon*) has a gratis version and can do that:

[image: Helium] [image: Helium] [image: Helium]
<sup>*Helium* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup); click images for larger variants)</sup>

It's quite a while since I last used it – but AFAIR it stored multiple sets for each app. You can decide whether the `.apk` should be included with backups as well (by default it's not), and setup groups of apps for scheduled auto-backups. A detailed howto can be found [here](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/how-to-backup-apps-and-data-without-root-using-helium-android-app-51677/); note that on rooted devices you can skip the "activation stuff" (which requires desktop interaction, and most likely does nothing but start a local ADB daemon to interact with).

Backed-up files are using the very same format as ADB's backup does, so the plus is you can even restore those from your PC. Using a file-sync app to sync your backups with your PC, you could even support more "backup sets" (e.g. using a script on your computer to round-robin-rename the target directory to something like `backup.[0-6]` (weekdays).

*Helium* has a paid version as well, supporting Cloud storage for those who like that.

Back then, I stuck with *TiBu* (more flexible, more features) – just wanted to see how *Helium* works. It's definitely easier to use than *TiBu* – but then, it has far less features to care for :) Btw: another plus of Helium's paid version is the ability to sync backups across devices: start a game on your phone while on the train from work, continue playing at your tablet when reaching home :)

Comment: Thanks Izzy!  Thumbs up.  Your last sentence refers to the Helium paid version, and not the TiBu paid version, correct?

Comment: Yupp, correct – let me edit that to make it more clear … Done :)